# Creating csv - some open, some need import into Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel-2010

I have a program written that creates three separate csv files.  One opens directly in Excel, the other two require an text file import.
The method and procedure are the same (except for the data written to the CSV.)

Works

```
Dim fso, MyFile 'tests writing from different Lists
    fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    MyFile = fso.createtextfile(OutPutfilePath, True)

    MyFile.WriteLine("Entry Key Number,Item Number,Part Number,Description,Part Sheet,Parent Level")
    For Each ENTRY_ As LDF_Test_1.ENTRY_ARRAY In ENTRY_ENTRY

        MyFile.writeline(ENTRY_.ENTRY_KEY & "," & ENTRY_.Entry_ItemNo & "," & ENTRY_.Entry_PartNo & ",""" & ENTRY_.Entry_Descrip & """," & ENTRY_.Entry_LIST_FileName & "," & ENTRY_.Entry_ParentNo)

    Next
    MyFile.close()
```

Doesn't work

```
    Dim fso, MyFile 'tests writing from different Lists
    fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    MyFile = fso.createtextfile(OutPutfilePath, True)

    MyFile.WriteLine("LDF File Name,LDF Ref,LDF Description,Folder Name,Pic File Name,Picture Title ,Destination Folder,Serial Number,Converted,end")
    For Each Pix_ As LDF_Test_1.PIX_ARRAY In PIX_PIX

        MyFile.writeline(Pix_.Pix_List_FileName & ",""" & Pix_.Pix_List_Ref & """,""" & Pix_.Pix_List_Descrip & """,""" & path_ & """,""" & Pix_.Pix_FileName & """,""" & Pix_.Pix_Title & """,""" & OutPutfilePath & """,""" & Serial_Num)

    Next
    MyFile.close()
    MsgBox("File Created")
```

Any ideas or thoughts?

Comment: And your using the `.csv` extension, right?

Comment: The problem might be the quotes.

Comment: Research using a StreamWriter object from the `System.IO` namespace. You don't need a `FileSystemObject` if this is on the `.Net` framework.

Comment: Open the created files in a text editor and look for mismatched double quotes.  The code above in the second snippet fails to place a double quote before the first field (and perhaps after the final field.) Test you work by inserting a double quote or two in one of the text fields. If a delimiter exists in the text then the delimiter character needs to be doubled up.

Answer (score 0):

Embedded Quotes are a pain and probably the source of "doesnt work" .  NET provides a great alternative to try:

```
  MyFile.writeline(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, ...etc",
     Pix_.Pix_List_FileName, Pix_.Pix_List_Ref,
     Pix_.Pix_List_Descrip, Pix_.Pix_FileName,
     etc)
```

Make sure you have the same number of holders as data elements.

Note: the code looks more like VBA than VB.NET,  but thats how you tagged it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the StreamWriter Object from the `System.IO` namespace:

```
Using myFile As New IO.StreamWriter(OutPutfilePath)
 myFile.WriteLine("LDF File Name,LDF Ref,
                   LDF Description,Folder Name,
                   Pic File Name,Picture Title ,Destination Folder,
                   Serial Number,Converted,end")
 For Each ENTRY_ As LDF_Test_1.ENTRY_ARRAY In ENTRY_ENTRY
   myFile.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}",
                    ENTRY_.ENTRY_KEY,ENTRY_.Entry_ItemNo,
                    ENTRY_.Entry_PartNo, ENTRY_.Entry_Descrip,
                    ENTRY_.Entry_LIST_FileName, ENTRY_.Entry_ParentNo)
 Next
End Using
```